# DAX: How to dynamicaly switch column for calculation?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate poll results. Poll answers are being gathered in excel file where column names are poll questions and each row contains answers to those questions (around 60 columns/questions).

I've created a table where I have the same questions in rows and I want to add calculated column which will calculate Average score for each question. So it should calculate:

```
AVERAGE('answers table '[**column name**])
```

*where*
[**column name**] = 'results table'[question] **row value**

Comment: Have you tried unpivotting your answers table to create one question column and one answer column? I don't believe dynamic evaluation of your DAX is possible in PowerBI.

Comment: Thank You, I just did it. It would be nice to have such possibility though because when I have 60 questions soterd like this and will have many answers it will be huge table. What I did not said is that there are also several columns with details regarding who was answering, which department, contact details, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Jelle Hoekstra* suggested a solution with unpivoting answers table which is working, yet my table grows quite rapidly because of that so if there is some way to do it like described, please share.

Comment: The lenght of your table is not relevant, the structure of your datais much more important. I believe the suggestion of Jelle is the correct way to go, it gives you all the flexibility you need to get the right statistics.